# How to say 'Exercise is also very important' (Hontō ni)

Tags: word-choice, particles

In context, I'm attempting to say 'For the sake of a long life, eating well is important but exercise is also very important'.
So far I have:

> 長生きのために　よく食べることが大切ですが、運動も本当に大切です。

Is the usage of hontō ni in this passage correct? If not, how can express this without too much deviation from this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

> 「長生{ながい}きのために　よく食{た}べることが大切{たいせつ}ですが、運動{うんどう}も本当{ほんとう}に大切{たいせつ}です。」

If you wanted as few corrections as possible, 「運動も本当に大切です」 could be left as is.  While it is not completely natural-sounding, it could not be called incorrect, either.

When you list mutiple things in Japanese, however, it is ideal to put them in the same grammatical form.  You used 「verb + こと」 for the first and 「noun only」 for the second.

Ideally, it should be either 「食べること」 and 「運動すること」 ***or*** 「食事」 and 「運動」.

The "real" problem with your sentence IMHO is actually the use of 「よく食べる」.  This was obtained by directly translating "***eat well***", was it not?  The truth is  that 「よく食べる」 can only mean "***eat a lot***" in Japanese.  A literal translation does not work here.

"To eat well" would be 「正{ただ}しい食事{しょくじ}をする」、「バランスの良{い}い食事をする」, etc.

Thus, the most natural way to list the two items would be:

1) Nouns: 「正しい食事」 and 「（適度{てきど}な）運動」

2) Verb + こと: 「正しい食事をすること」 and 「（適度に）運動すること」